# How can I parse double from a string?

Tags: c++

I have the following code but it only converts strings to double. if the string contains a letter, it causes an error

```
 while (cin >> s){
        const char *c_ptr=s.c_str();
        d = atof(c_ptr);
        v.push_back(d);
    }
```

I want to input a string like "a1.2 3 4b"  and have the  vector populated with "1.2 3 4"

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/

Comment: sscanf will work only if you know how many doubles you are reading ahead of time as well as what non-numerical characters the string has.

Comment: What if the input is "4a1.2"? How many numbers should go into the vector? If only one, what should its value be?

Comment: You have to either define your input exactly to match c++ types ie char double space int int, or you are going to have to use regex

Comment: That's a false dichotomy, @Adrian.

Comment: @Rob - you are correct. What I was trying to say (badly albeit) was that the input requirements needs to be firmly defined. Ie 1 char 1 int 1 space 2 char. Or 0-10char 1+spaces etc. Basically you cannot safety parser input unless you can guarantee the input format. In OP's original example is the 4b at the end a hex string or a int + char or a char[2] or a var length string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
1) replace all chars in the string that aren't digits or decimal points by spaces
2) read doubles in a loop
```

since you got rid of the letters before parsing the doubles, they should no longer cause issues.

Comment: sounds like a good idea. how do you use the replace function to replace these characters? i cant get str.replace() to work on c++

Comment: P.S. you're probably going to want to use istringstream for step 2 since your code above will only get a single double from each string. See http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/54367 for an example.

Comment: Easiest way I can think of is to just do the replacement yourself in a for loop. A similar example can be seen here http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/349806